# How would I get the ID of a created file using python and the Google Docs API?

Tags: python, google-docs-api

I am writing a simple python program to collect information and format it into a google doc. I want the program to create the document, then add text to it. I can create a program easily, and I've had no trouble adding text to existing documents. However, I can't access the ID of the created document within the program, so I can't add text to it. How do I get the ID of a document that I've created within the same program I want to edit it in?

Comment: Can you post an example of the code you've tried?  There are multiple ways to create Google documents with the API - both the Drive and Docs (and Sheets) APIs have a create document feature.

Comment: Sure. This is what I'm using to create the document:

`doc = docsService.documents().create(body=body).execute()`

This is more or less exactly as described in the "create a document" section of the API reference. However, the "insert text" section from the same reference features the line:

`result = docsService.documents().batchUpdate(documentId=, body={'requests': requests}).execute()`

For execution, which requires a doc ID, which I can't seem to get without opening the doc manually and copying from the URL.

Comment: You have the object doc, so to get document Id, you just need to call docId = doc.get('documentId')

Comment: Ah, I’m just an idiot. I was trying with “get(‘docId’)” for some reason. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Follow steps 1 and 2 as documented on the following link:
https://developers.google.com/docs/api/quickstart/python

And then try the following code:

```
import pickle
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents']
creds = None

if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
  with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
    creds = pickle.load(token)

# If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
if not creds or not creds.valid:
  if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
    creds.refresh(Request())
  else:
    flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file('/content/credentials.json', SCOPES)
    #creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
    creds = flow.run_console()
  # Save the credentials for the next run
  with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
      pickle.dump(creds, token)

service = build('docs', 'v1', credentials=creds)

title = 'My Test Document'
body = {
    'title': title
}
doc = service.documents().create(body=body).execute()
docId = doc.get('documentId')
print( 'Id of new Document is : ' + docId )
```

**NOTE:**
Place the file `credentials.json` at appropriate location and set the path in code accordingly.